# Running a kivy program on Android

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

First of all i am aware that there have been alot of similair questions asked already, but somehow i cant figure anything out, I have a python-kivy program that I want to run on Android, the program works perfectly on my computer, I've ran various simple programs using Python Interpreter with Kivy, so far it was the best open source I could find, but there is some nasty problems with it.
I've been to https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android and since i already had Kivy Launcher installed on my phone i tried that one first, however when i open the app i get a message:

No projects are available to luanch. Please place a project into storage/emulated/0/kivy and restart this application. Press back button to exit.

at https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android I readed that the 'project' consists of my main code, lets say main.py, and android.txt, the android.txt must contain a few things that i wont mention now, these two files must be placed in a folder and placed at the asked directory.

I did this, but i still got the same message.

I've thought of trying Buildozer, but i did not seem to find a proper instalation for it on android.

I'm asking advice, becouse i think that the answer to my problems might not be so dificuilt, so any advice apreciated.

Thanks and regards.

Cid-El

ps. Android Lollipop, python 3.4

Comment: I have been using `buildozer` number of times and without any problem. What issues you have for the installation? Also you will install `buildozer` on your machine, packaging for Android and push to device directly -- you don't need to install anything in Android apart from allowing developer options

Comment: ok, i thought that buildozer required installing on phone, and since i could not find a download at play store i thought it was a dead end, can you explain how to use it?

Comment: it's too long to type in comment, I've put on an answer showing the basic flow how to init and run your app locally. hope it helps you get going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using **buildozer** to package your app and deploy to Android device directly for debug, you only need to install this in your machine, and change the developer options in Android to allow external source.

Basically once you install the **buildozer**, you need to initialise a project by:
`buildozer init`

Make sure you have the required dependencies and targeted Android SDK/NDK in your system.

Then it's only a simple edit the build manifest for Python specific dependencies (external modules etc).

And run locally by:
`buildozer android deploy run`

Read more about **buildozer** [here](https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#init-and-build-for-android)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am running out of time right now, but i hope to try to get it working later today, or next weak

Comment: @Cid-El, yea sure, just give SO a shout if you tried and got stuck we are here to help :)

Comment: hi Anzel, i tried Buildozer just now, but i get a super long error (after I've installed alot of other packages on request), but thanks for the help though

Comment: I've been to another website, and there I found another way to build a apk using buildozer, thanks for your help!